# Java Inner Interfaces

Tags: java

```
class Test {
       private interface Inner {
          void show();
       }
   }
class TestDemo implements Test.Inner {
     public void show(){ }
}
```

In above code Inner Interface is private member of class Test.so we cant access outside of another class.if  Above code is wrong what is the is use of Private inner interface in class.

Comment: It can be used privately, within the `Test` class. What's your question?

Comment: If You want to learn about interfaces, please go through some Java tutorials or books, SO is a website for programming issues and debugging.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "inner interface" in Java. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1

Answer (score 2):

It can be used for inner classes of the same class

```
class Test {
       private interface Inner {
          void show();
       }
       class InnerClass1 implements Inner  {
          public void show(){ }
       }
       class InnerClass2 implements Inner  {
          public void show(){ }
       }
   }
```